# React redirect to hompage from every url and on refresh

Tags: reactjs, react-router

When I refresh the page or when I type the path to the URL or when I follow the link to the site I always get to the main page. I tracked the path using the debugger, first I get to the right page, it appears, and then I get to the main page.

App.js:

```
<div className="wrapper">
      {localStorage.email != "" ?
        (
          <AuthProvider>
            <Router>
              <div>
                <Switch>
                  <div className="wrapper">
                    <Route render={MainComponent} />


                  </div>
                </Switch>
              </div>
            </Router>
          </AuthProvider>
        ) : (
          <AuthProvider>
            <Router>
              <div>
                <Switch>
                  <div className="wrapper">
                    <Route path="/login" exact render={LoginComponent} />
                    <Route path="/signup" exact component={SignUpComponent} />
                    <Route path="/forgetpass" exact render={ForgetPassComponent} />
                    <Redirect from='*' to='/login' />
                  </div>
                </Switch>
              </div>
            </Router>
          </AuthProvider>
        )}
</div>
```

Main.js:

```
<div className="content">
                <Redirect exact from='/login' to='/' />
                <Redirect exact from='/signup' to='/' />
                <Route exact path="/" render={publicComponent} />

                <Route exact path="/other" render={otherComponent} />
</div>
```